# Storing JsonObjects in an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to store a multiple JsonObjects in ArrayList to parse and display in tableview at later stage.

for some odd reason I can't add objects to the list.

```
I am using javax.json
```

Here is my Try statement:

```
try {
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.creatReader(new StringReader(test));
    JsonObject obj = jsonReader.readObject();
    jsonReader.close();
    key = obj.getString("key"); // this works with no issue
    ArrayList<JsonObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<>();
    jsonList.add(obj); // everything hangs with no errors when I try to do this

}
```

debugger shows jsonList size 0 obj size 3 for this line

```
jsonList.add(obj);
```

if I commented these lines everything works as expected

```
ArrayList<JsonObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<>();
jsonList.add(obj);
```

when they are not commented I am getting catch final throwable (be sure to set the state after the cause of failure.

Comment: Use your debugger and pause execution to see where your application has hung.

Comment: The state of `jsonList` irrelevant. If your application has hung, then it means the thread (likely the main thread) your code is running on is blocked for some reason. Pause execution in your debugger and inspect the main thread. It should show you a call stack indicating what the next instruction is , which is where it would be blocked. This of course depends on which tool / debugger you're using.

Comment: What if you move `jsonReader.close()` to the end of the try block?

Comment: it's still not working, please see updates

Comment: You should close the reader in a `finally` block, but I don't think that's the issue